# How to remove Your carrier may charge for SMS Messages used to activate FaceTime

Tags: iphone, sms, facetime, messages

This message keeps coming back:
"Your carrier may charge for SMS Messages used to activate FaceTime"

I managed to get rid of it before but when I change the SIM card it pops up again.

It's similar to "Your carrier may charge for SMS messages used to activate iMessage", which I got rid of this time but I don't remember how.

How to quickly ensure both these messages don't pop up:

- Your carrier may charge for SMS messages used to activate iMessage
- Your carrier may charge for SMS Messages used to activate FaceTime

Ideally forever, but I'm ok with a quick solution that I can quickly find back here on Ask Different.

Oh and I want to keep Facetime enabled. Not sure about iMessage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Source](https://macreports.com/carrier-may-charge-sms-messages-used-activate-imessage/)

You didn't mention the iOS version you're using so I'm assuming you're on the 11.1.2.  Here's a few things to try (not in any particular order):

1. Make sure that your date, time, and time zone are set correctly. Turn Messages off and on in `Settings > Messages`. Open Message, under the Message settings, a popup message will appear saying your carrier may charge for SMS messages and select “Cancel”. Message activates itself after you have clicked Cancel.
2. Make sure that your iPhone has the latest version of iOS. In not, backup your iPhone and then simply update.
3. Remove and reinsert the Sim card. Apple [explains how you can do that](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201337).
4. Tap `Settings > Your Name (and iCloud ID)`. Then tap `Name, Phone numbers, Email`. Under **Reachable At** tap `Edit` and add your phone number.
5. Reset network settings. Go to `Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings`.  As the action states, this will reset your network settings (e.g. your Wi-Fi passwords will be removed etc).

If you are still having this problem, contact your cell carrier (AT&T, T-Mobile etc.). You may also contact Apple support.

Answer (score 1):

For me it went away when I did a test iMessage and FaceTime call to a friend. After that, the messages didn’t appear anymore.

Comment: This is how it’s designed, but software can fail, preferences can be corrupt and carriers can mess up. Good to have this clear since I don’t think the question is clear if the person is causing deactivation and all is working as designed. +1

Answer (score 0):

I solved this message reinstalling FaceTime. I had uninstalled it because i do not use but for some reason iOS produces this message if FaceTime is not installed